# Nice Scroll não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

Preciso deixar a minha página com a rolagem suave. Pesquisando na comunidade encontrei o plugin chamado *nice scroll*. Implementei ele e funcionou apenas no Google Chrome e no Opera, mas não no Mozilla Firefox e no Safari. Segue meu código abaixo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Nova Era Team</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("html").niceScroll();
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>
  <p>teste</p>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dá um inspect element, vai em console e copia aqui o erro que tá dando, por favor.

Comment: Qual versão do firefox você utiliza? no firefox developer 40.0a2 está funcionando

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo o [SmoothScroll](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/37fe91076381ebb8d293256f0424ab6520150522165544/29604d06909946889e8355c44894a6b220150522165544/d77961#) sem nenhum problema.

Basta baixar e adicionar a chamada abaixo no arquivo de rodapé das suas páginas:

`<script src="SEU_DIRETORIO/SmoothScroll.js"></script>`